# Why are some characters "not valid" even though they show up in strings?

Tags: unicode

I'm looking into what appears to be a text encoding issue in my app. I'm finding that some characters, like [U+C5D0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c5d0/index.htm) and [U+BE60](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/be60/index.htm) show up as not valid on FileFormat. Why is this? Are they expected to be combined with another character?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. They are not valid, period. The Unicode docs say that. The fact that they show up in strings in your app doesn't make them valid, it just means you have a bug somewhere.

Comment: @sashoalm can you link to those Unicode docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are valid in Unicode 9.0 at least.  They are Hangul syllables.  Perhaps FileFormat is quoting an older specification. See http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UAC00.pdf.

Comment: codepoints.net thinks it was added to Unicode in version 2.0...https://codepoints.net/U+C5D0?lang=en

Comment: @TomHamming So more likely just a bug on FileFormat.  I looked at the pages for the listed points and there is a "not valid" message, but then it goes on and describes the character anyway.

Comment: Even though FileFormat lists these characters as invalid, it also lists them as being in the [`HANGUL_SYLLABLES`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/hangul_syllables/index.htm) block of characters.  So it clearly knows about them.